# what is dynamic stored procedure ? what is their relation with dynamic functions and dynamic queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do we implement dynamic stored procedure and do they relate to dynamic functions and dynamic queries in sql server ?

Kindly enlighten...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only dynamic SQL which refers to the practice of creating a T-SQL text and executing it using the [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) (or simply [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)): [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Stored procedures can execute dynamic SQL, functions cannot.