# SQL CASE statment to select which table to UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to use the CASE statement to decide which table to update...

I.E.

```
IF (@existingStep = 1)
 BEGIN  
   UPDATE 
    CASE @tableToUpdate
      WHEN 'TemplateActionSettings' THEN TemplateActionSetting SET blah blah blah

    WHEN 'ETC' THEN --DO THIS ONE

 END
```

Can CASE be used in this manner?

Comment: please tag what DBMS you are using

Comment: No, `CASE` is not a statement for control of flow like it is in some languages (e.g. VB). `CASE` is an expression that returns a single scalar value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately CASE cannot be used like this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use IF instead to get something similar

```
IF @TableToUpdate = 'Table1'
BEGIN
UPDATE U SET Col = 'Val' FROM Table1 AS U WHERE something = something
END
ELSE IF @TableToUpdate = 'Table2'
BEGIN
UPDATE U SET Col1 = 'Val' FROM Table2 AS U WHERE something = something
END
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to use but thought it would be easier to read (and save space) if I could set it up with the CASE statement... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use the case in a straight SQL statement.  You will have to use procedural language to accomplish this.  I assume you are using a RDMS.

Comment: Thanks everyone... that would explain why I couldn't figure out the syntax. Ya, I'm using TSQL and SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in SQL unless you use dynamic queries(eg: string concat followed by execute in SQL server style). Each DML statement must identify what object(ie table) it is operating on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an update statement to multiple tables like that; unless you can create a view that spans all your tables and will still work with updates. if you can create that view you would use update on cases and set data back to original value if it hasn't changed. If not you will need to use  [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585647/what-is-dynamic-stored-procedure-what-is-their-relation-with-dynamic-functions)