# how to select columns from a table set in parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using the following procedure in one of my projects.

```
create procedure [dbo].[SMSStudentSelect2]
@Sorp char(20)
as
begin
   select @Sorp PhoneNo from Students 
   where DATALENGTH(@Sorp) = 11 and ClassId = 1 
   and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)
end
```

my problem is: when I put `SPhoneNo` in the parameter `@Sorp` I get no result while when i directly use `SPhoneNo` i.e I use the query like

```
select SPhoneNo from Students where DATALENGTH(SPhoneNo) = .........
```

in my procedure, I Get the disired result

Can anyone please solve my problem????

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585647/what-is-dynamic-stored-procedure-what-is-their-relation-with-dynamic-functions

Comment: @u17ch why don't you update my question if you know how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** based on comments to determine what the OP wants:

try something like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[SMSStudentSelect2]
@Sorp char(1) --"S" returns the SPhoneNo, "P" returns the PPhoneNo
as
begin
   select
       CASE
           WHEN @Sorp='S' THEN SPhoneNo 
           ELSE PPhoneNo 
       END AS PhoneNo
       from Students 
       where DATALENGTH(@Sorp) = 11 and ClassId = 1 
           and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)
end
```

pass in a "S" or  a "P" to get the column you want.

Comment: +1, this is better than dynamics and will work just fine except for the where clause `DATALENGTH(@Sorp) = 11`. Need to use a case there as well to use the actual column(s).

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson, I'm not sure about the `DATALENGTH(@Sorp)` part. @Sorp is declared char(20), and the OP says they are passing in "SPhoneNo" and "PPhoneNo" (so where does the `` come from?).  Possibly just remove it and make the where be: `where ClassId = 1 and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)`

Comment: Thanks KM and Mikael Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

arent you missing a = sign here:

```
select @Sorp = PhoneNo
```

Comment: I'm seeing this a little differently, `select @Sorp PhoneNo from Students ...` is valid, it will return the given @Sorp value in a result set with the column name "PhoneNo" when the `WHERE` finds a matching row.  when you say `select @Sorp=PhoneNo from Students ...` you are trying to put the value from a `PhoneNo` column into the input parameter @Sorp, which doesn't make any sense.  possibly the OP needs to add `OUTPUT` onto the parameter and use the `=` like you are suggesting?  I'm not sure the question isn't worded very clearly.

Comment: but the way it is, he is only going to get nulls as a result set

Comment: @KM - I have a third view on this. I think OP wants to dynamically specify the column to use in the result set. Meaning that he has to build the query dynamically as in the link to the question provided by u07ch.

Comment: i request you guys to please create an example of it and try it.

Comment: Note: when i was using the same query directly from my application i.e without using procedure i was getting the desired result. i was using it like this. cmd.commandtext = "select " + cbsorp.Text + " PhoneNo from Students where DATALENGTH(" + cbsorp.Text + ") = 11 and ClassId = " + cbclass.SelectedValue + " and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)" Note: combobox cbsorp contains to display member SPhoneNo and PPhoneNo

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson, yes, based on the latest comments, I think you are right, the OP is trying to pass in a column name and have the query return the data for it.  this looks like an injection attack waiting to happen, with a screen passing the column name to the DB.  Try passing in `1; delete Students--`  I'd go with a `CASE` within the query, or an large `IF ELSE` structure based on the parameter to eliminate the injection possibilities.

Comment: I actually want to select one of two columns from my students table. either SPhoneNo or PPhoneNo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KM. as  Mikael Eriksson suggested I used the case with data length as well. and my problem is solved as follows

```
alter procedure [dbo].[SMSStudentSelect2]
@Sorp char(1) --"S" returns the SPhoneNo, "P" returns the PPhoneNo
as
begin
   select
       CASE
           WHEN @Sorp='S' THEN SPhoneNo 
           ELSE PPhoneNo 
       END AS PhoneNo
       from Students 
       where DATALENGTH(case when @Sorp = 'S' then SPhoneNo else PPhoneNo end)= 11 and ClassId = 1 
           and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)
end
GO
```

I'm sorry to be able to reward you the only reputations that are rewarded when an answer is accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can write this stored procedure to use dynamic SQL.

create procedure [dbo].[SMSStudentSelect2]
@Sorp char(20)
as
begin

DECLARE @SQL AS nvarchar(max) =

'select ' + @Sorp + ' AS PhoneNo from Students 
   where ' + LENGTH(@Sorp) + ' = 11 and ClassId = 1 
   and GRNo not in(select GRNo from Discharge)'

EXEC(@sql)

end

It's not the fastest code, but it will return your expect results.